# MPAndroidChart:- How to reduce the distance between the x axis points in a line chart?

Tags: android, linechart, mpandroidchart

I am plotting a real time data using MPAndroidChart. The X axis and Y axis are defined as below. Data is populating to the graph without any issues. The result is supposed to be in a wave form. Since the Y axis range is too high I am getting the values as lines. Could anyone help me on how to adjust the X axis range based on the Y axis vale, so that it can plot the values correctly.

```
    XAxis xl = mChart.getXAxis();
    xl.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    xl.setDrawGridLines(false);
    xl.setDrawLabels(false);
    xl.setAvoidFirstLastClipping(true);
    xl.setSpaceBetweenLabels(5);
    xl.setEnabled(true);

    YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
    leftAxis.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    leftAxis.setAxisMaxValue(4000f);
    leftAxis.setAxisMinValue(-4000f);
    leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(true);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the chart property chart.setVisibleXRange(100,100) properly solved my issue. There was nothing to do with the X-axis value.